# Retaining bash prompt colors when starting a screen session

Tags: 10.04, command-line, ssh, gnu-screen

When I ssh into a Ubuntu Lucid box the prompt is all pretty, with colors. Everything is the default, as far as I know. Here's my $PS1 outside screen:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@dev\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

[image: Before connecting with screen]

But then once I start screen up the colors go away. Everything else is fine, and my screen can support colors (notice that the `.` and `..` in this `ls -al` are blue) but the prompt isn't. In theory everything should be exactly the same. $PS1 inside screen:

```
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@dev:\w\$
```

[image: after screening in]

EDIT: This is just plain vanilla screen.

Comment: Is this plain vanilla screen, or do you have byobu installed?  (Though this matter not matter.)

Comment: Does `echo $PS1` print the same thing inside screen and outside screen?

Comment: $PS1 is indeed different. Edited question to include that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can edit the following line in your .bashrc (it's #39 in my .bashrc):

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

Change to:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

This could possibly be annoying if you log in from somewhere where color is not supported, but i find it highly unlikely.

Comment: Perfect, that did it for me.  I can see it being problematic if I happen to login from somewhere without color, but that's going to be pretty rare. Thanks!

Comment: The change needs to be done on the server machine, not the client.

Comment: Nice, allows to keep host color with GNU Screen in local.

Answer (score 4):

Screen normally uses a special terminal type, such as "screen", or if you set it in your .screenrc, "screen-256color".

Just look in your .bashrc for the color detection case statement and add screen to the list.

For example, something like this:

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm)
        color_prompt=yes
        ;;
    screen)
        color_prompt=yes
        ;;
    *256*) 
        color_prompt=yes
        ;;
esac
```

I use 256-color terminal types, so I just need the *256* case statement, since it catches xterm-256color, gnome-256color, and screen-256color. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: This looks like the _cleanest_ way to enable color for screen sessions.

Answer (score 3):

The `.screenrc` file is a mystery to me. Mine is gobbledygook that I copypasta'd from the internets. However, I see a few lines that look to be relevant to your problem:

```
# terminfo and termcap for nice 256 color terminal
# allow bold colors - necessary for some reason
attrcolor b ".I" 
# tell screen how to set colors. AB = background, AF=foreground
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
```

I think if you add the above lines to yours, you'll get colour. Here's my whole `.screenrc` for reference:

```
jake@daedalus:~$ cat .screenrc 
startup_message off # skip splash screen
vbell off # Kill the annoying dog

# Voodoo
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= wk}%-Lw%{= KW}%50>%n%f* %t%{= dK}%+Lw%<'

# terminfo and termcap for nice 256 color terminal
# allow bold colors - necessary for some reason
attrcolor b ".I" 
# tell screen how to set colors. AB = background, AF=foreground
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
# erase background with current bg color 
defbce "on"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `PS1` setting should be placed in `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`.

If that is not the problem, please edit your question to include the line you have set `PS1` to.

You could also try running these:

```
echo "$TERM"                                 # will probably print "screen"
tput setaf 2 | cat -vte                      # should print "^[[32m"
echo "$(tput setaf 2)"green"$(tput sgr0)"    # should print "green" in green
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your ~/.screenrc

```
shell -$SHELL
```

Comment: +1. This got me back my nice looking bash prompt on OS X.

Comment: @Cam , it works on a HPC, what does it does ?

Answer (score 1):

Invoking screen with `-T xterm` works for me, so simply:

```
screen -T xterm
```

No need to modify any files.